# Bash how to repeat all program

Tags: bash, loops

How do that, to script at the end started everything from beginning, or if i wrote for example stop it will be stopped ?

```
whole program
.
.
. 
echo "enter word or enter "enter"
back to start or end
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing is to write:

```
  exec $0 "$@"
```

at the end of the script (assuming you haven't changed any of the positional parameters).  Otherwise; put `while true: do` at the start and `done` at the end.

Comment: +1 In addition to the positional parameters, one should be aware if any of the environment variables changed value, and whether or not that is an issue.